# QMetaEnum: To use with defines?

Tags: c++, qt

I have an enum whose contents will vary based off of operating system.  So, I want to do something like:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    enum AudioRenderer
    {
        Null,
        OpenAL,
        XAudio2
    };
#endif
#ifdef __LINUX
    enum AudioRenderer
    {
        Null,
        OpenAL,
        ALSA
    };
#endif
Q_ENUM(AudioRenderer)
```

Later, I will call:

```
QMetaEnum::fromType<AudioRenderer>();
```

and do things with it. In this case, convert the enum to a string to write to a settings file.

However, whenever I attempt to do this, it appears the metaenum's internal mobj is null. (Taken from visual studio debugger)

```
+       metaEnum    {mobj=0x0000000000000000 <NULL> handle=0 }  QMetaEnum
```

I can step through part of Qt's code (I downloaded it normally but you can still follow the include headers).  Here we find:

```
template<typename T> static QMetaEnum fromType() {
    Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QtPrivate::IsQEnumHelper<T>::Value,
                      "QMetaEnum::fromType only works with enums declared as Q_ENUM or Q_FLAG");
    const QMetaObject *metaObject = qt_getEnumMetaObject(T());
    const char *name = qt_getEnumName(T());
    return metaObject->enumerator(metaObject->indexOfEnumerator(name));
}
```

It grabs the name correctly, but the last line still returns the invalid metaenum.

Is there any way around this?  Can I use processor defines with Qt meta enums?  If I remove the preprocessor command and just have the enum as is.  The code will work.  It seems like the preprocessor breaks something.

I'm using Qt 5.8.

Comment: I feel like `moc` doesn't know those two macros because they are _compiler predefined_ macros. You might have better luck with `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN` and `Q_OS_LINUX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but since you observed it to only be a problem with the preprocessor commands in there I'd assume that Qts MOC can't handle preprocessor commands and just ignores them, thus trying to register two enums with the same name in the same namespace - which apparently doesn't work correctly.

There is a workaround, though: Qt5.8 introduced the [`Q_ENUM_NS`](https://www.kdab.com/new-qt-5-8-meta-object-support-namespaces/) macro that allows to register enums with the Qt Metaobject system at namespace scope. Together with inline namespaces, you can do the following:

```
#  ifdef _WIN32
inline
#  endif
namespace audio_win32 {
    Q_NAMESPACE
    enum AudioRenderer
    {
        Null,
        OpenAL,
        XAudio2
     };
     Q_ENUM_NS(AudioRenderer)
} // namespace audio_win32

#ifdef _LINUX
inline
#endif
namespace audio_linux {
    Q_NAMESPACE
    enum AudioRenderer
    {
        Null,
        OpenAL,
        ALSA
    };
    Q_ENUM_NS(AudioRenderer)
} // namespace audio_linux
```

Since both enums live in a different namespace, MOC doesn't have a problem  registering them both, and since only the namespace for the current platform is inlined, the name `AudioRenderer` in `QMetaEnum::fromType<AudioRenderer>();` always refers to correct one.

In order to use the `Q_NAMESPACE` macro you need to `#include <QObject>` in the header file that defines these enums.

Comment: That will work though it isn't ideal since it feels a bit clunky compared to using the preprocessor.  But, I appreciate the idea.  And, if nothing better comes in the next couple days, I'll mark this as accepted. It just felt like a bug to me since the code compiles, but didn't work in runtime.

Comment: @flash_fire It is still using the preprocessor to select the namespace to inline. I agree that the problem you encountered is a bug in MOC and it shouldn't have compiled in the first place.